# Can I avoid all this multiples try/catch

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-any

I have a vector of many boost::any
In this vector I need to perform some operations on std::vector and on the elements of type IContainer

```
class   IContainer
{
public:
  virtual ~IContainer(){}
  virtual const boost::any operator[](std::string) const = 0;
};

class   AContainer : public IContainer
{
  std::vector<int>      vect_;
  std::string name_;
public:
  AContainer() : vect_({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), name_("AContainer") {}
  virtual const boost::any operator[](std::string key) const
  {
    if (key == "str")
      return (name_);
    if (key == "vect")
      return (vect_);
    return nullptr;
  }
};
```

So I have done the following function (imo quite ugly) but who works correctly

m is `const std::vector<boost::any>&`

```
for (const auto & elem : m)
    {
      try
        {
          std::vector<int> v = boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(elem);
          display(v);
        }
      catch(boost::bad_any_cast){}
      try
        {
          std::vector<IContainer*> v = boost::any_cast<std::vector<IContainer*>>(elem);
          display(v);
        }
      catch(boost::bad_any_cast){}
      try
        {
          AContainer v(boost::any_cast<AContainer>(elem));
          try
            {
              display(boost::any_cast<const std::vector<int>>(v["vect"]));
            }
          catch (boost::bad_any_cast){}
          try
            {
              std::cout << boost::any_cast<const std::string>(v["str"]) << std::endl;
            }
          catch (boost::bad_any_cast){}
          try
            {
              display(boost::any_cast<std::vector<int> >(v));
            }
          catch (boost::bad_any_cast) {}
        }
      catch(boost::bad_any_cast){}
    }
```

I have tried to add many "`try{}try{}catch{}`" but it's not working

Do you have any solutions better than what I have done

***Edit***

I have tried the solutions of James Kanze, user1131467 and Praetorian

So the 3 are working nicely, but when I have calculate the time of execution, the answer of user1131467 is a bit faster than the other. I must now find a solution to store each types in a map to avoid all this if/else

I will also take a look at boost::variant

Comment: Are you sure that `boost::any` is the right tool for the job? Have you considered different approaches like `boost::variant`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the pointer-form of `any_cast` is much cleaner, as it uses the nullability of pointers:

```
for (const auto & elem : m)
    if (T1* p = any_cast<T1>(&elem))
    {
         do stuff with *p;
    }
    else if (T2* p = any_cast<T2>(&elem))
    {
         do stuff with *p;
    }
    else if (...)
    {
         ...
    }
```

This also has the advantage of doing the cast once per case.

Comment: `boost::any_cast` will return a null pointer, rather than throw, if the cast fails.  You can also use `if ( elem.type() == typeid(TargetType) )` if there's no polymorphism.  But while defining the pointers in the condition might be legal, it's very bad programming practice: it's better to do the `if`, then *if you need the pointer* define it within the controlled block.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Why do you think it is bad programming practice?

Comment: Because it leads to unreadable code.  And `if` statement controls flow.  It doesn't change state or introduce additional variables.  (Having said that: this is a limit case where it might be justified.  And your solution is certainly better than all those which try to play tricks with `try`/`catch`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: A `for` statement controls flow as well, and also permits a declaration.  You wouldn't argue that `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` is bad programming practice.

Comment: A `for` statement _always_ defines a variable, so you know that the definition is there.  Defining more than one variable in a `for`, or defining the variable in the condition, wouldn't be the best practice.  (But as usual, there are exceptions.  This might be one, although to tell the truth, I probably wouldn't write it as a sequence of `if ... else if ...` anyway.  More likely a `map<type_index, FncPtr>`, looked up using `elem.type()`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: _"A for statement always defines a variable"_: The following for statement does not declare a variable `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {...}`.  Your statements about best practice are personal opinions given without sound rationale.

Comment: I probably miss-worded it: a `for` statement usually defines a variable.  It doesn't have to, but part of the reason for using `for` instead of `while` is that it can.  And code readability isn't purely subjective: statements which do more than one thing do make code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a function along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
bool 
isInstanceOf( boost::any const& object )
{
    return boost::any_cast<T>( &object ) != nullptr;
}
```

and use it, with if's to check:

```
if ( isInstanceOf<std::vector<int>>( elem ) ) {
    display( boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>( elem ) );
} else if ( isInstanceOf<std::vector<IContainer*>>( elem) ) {
    display( boost::any_cast<std::vector<IContainer*>>( elem) );
} 
//  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have chosen the other one since I don't have to call 2 times the any_cast

Comment: @Alexis: You shouldn't blindly pick what you accepted. The approach in this answer is much better at least in the sense that it won't cause a huge amount of exceptions in your system (which might be expensive).

Comment: My answer is superior to both as (a) it doesn't use exceptions; (b) requires only calling `any_cast` once (not twice) per case; and (c) doesn't require defining new functions.

Comment: @user1131467 On the other hand, your answer results in a lot of extra pointer variables floating around.  If you give them different names, there is a risk of using the wrong one because of a typo, and if you give them the same name, there is the risk of warnings from the compiler because of masking, or problems with the debugger for the same reason.  (On the other hand, my solution requires repeating the type name twice, which isn't ideal either.  In the end, an `std::map<type_index, PtrFnc>` indexed by `elem.type()` is probably a better solution.)

Comment: _"if you give them the same name, there is the risk of warnings from the compiler because of masking"_: hiding a variable from an outer scope in an inner scope is standard and well-formed, and does not produce a warning or problems with the debugger.  If you were really paranoid about that you can always terminate each case with a jump statement, and then use if rather then else-if.  I agree that if there are lots of cases an `unordered_map<type_index, lambda>` is more performant than all solutions so far discussed.

Comment: @user1131467 It's standard and well formed, but generally considered bad programming practice: some compilers do warn when it occurs, and I seem to remember having problems with a debugger when I accidentally did it.  And there is, at least until the profiler says otherwise, no argument with regards to performance: code with a single access to a map is probable easier to read and to understand than a sequence of a large number of `if ... else if...`.  (More generally, a `switch` or a sequence of `if .. else if` is probably to be avoided except for values from user input.)

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own wrapper around `any_cast` that swallows exceptions.

```
template<typename T>
bool nothrow_any_cast( boost::any& source, T& out )
{
  try {
    out = boost::any_cast<T>( source );
  } catch ( boost::bad_any_cast const& ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then use it as

```
std::vector<int> vect;
std::string str;

if( nothrow_any_cast(v["vect"], vect ) ) {
  // succeeded
} else if( nothrow_any_cast(v["str"], str ) ) {
  // succeeded
} ...
```

However, if you do this, you're default constructing all the types, and then assigning them; so even if it looks a little cleaner, it's debatable whether it is any better than what you already have.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for something like that.

Comment: That is still horrible, the horror being just hidden under the covers... It also requires the definition of the variables in the enclosing scope, and still causes a huge amount of exceptions...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree, James' answer is better than mine (I wasn't aware of the pointer overload for `any_cast`)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of the statements in one try block:

```
try {
    // do all your stuff
}
catch (boost::bad_any_cast) {}
```

Comment: yes but for exemple if it's a vector<int> I must perform one operation and then stop, not go at the next line. and if I have a vector<string> on the second line it's never going to reach it because the exception will be thrown before

Comment: If you want something like that you might be able to do some exception handling with your catch statement and re-direct based upon the error thrown.  Otherwise I think you're stuck with what you've got

Comment: It's what I was scared of, just asking to see if people have other ideas

Comment: One thing to do if you REALLY WANTED on try block (though I think this is uglier) is to set unique booleans to true after each successfully completed line.  Then based in your catch block you can use a goto to go to the next line after the line that threw an exception.  Personally I think what you have now is cleaner

Comment: @sedavidw There's no need for _any_ `try` blocks in his code.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add any instruction when entering your `catch(...){}` block. So when an exception is thrown you do not handle it at all.

An appropriate handling usually includes to trace the level of error and try to resolve the state of error (if possible).

Since in every branch you do catch the same exception you can aggregate all of them to one block:

```
try{ ... }
catch(boost::bad_any_cast) { ...}
```

Comment: The following code is working I don't want to perform any thing, just go the next try/catch block
I would have loved to have some if/elseif/else with dynamic_cast but it's not working with boost::any

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the pointer alternative of boost::any_cast, it does not throw anything, it returns nullptr if the requested type does not match with the store type.
And if you get a pointer back, you can just write an overload for display, that takes any
pointer, checks it for being null and calls the actual display function if the pointer is not null.

```
template<typename T>
void display(T* p) { if ( p ) display(*p); }
```

With the template above, only display is called for the correct cast.

```
for ( const auto& elem : m ) {
  display(boost::any_cast<int>(&elem));
  display(boost::any_cast<my_type>(&elem));
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answeres go the simple way that is now in the standard.

If you use "std::any" then you can just use the "type()" function to get the typeid of the containing item.